# How can I exclude a web site from StackExchange feed?

Tags: feature-request, feed

I saw that question on my StackExchange "hot questions" feed yesterday:

[Why Did Mrs. Crouch Die While Taking Polyjuice Potion?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/23226/why-did-mrs-crouch-die-while-taking-polyjuice-potion)

I share it here as is since the community explained that it was not a spoiler because the book was published too long ago and Internet is the place where we should expect to see such spoilers anywhere. They could be right about how old that was but still what if a question "not that old to me" comes into the feed?

That made me uncomfortable. I don't want to leave my exposure to spoilers to someone else's discretion and I think the best option is to opt-out from receiving hot questions on SciFi.StackExchange. How can I do that? Would it work if I delete my account on SciFi?

Comment: Definitely make this a feature request.

Comment: I added feature-request tag. Is that enough?

Comment: I believe so. :)

Comment: @ssg: apparently not. Nothing happened in the intervening ~1.5 years.

Comment: @DanDascalescu well, one thing changed. I stopped looking at hot questions after it was moved to its own page.

Comment: Was it moved back? Because I see "Hot Network Questions" right here, in the lower-right side of this page. Including some BS question from Bible Hermeneutics, which I'd very much like to remove from my Hot Network.

Comment: @DanDascalescu oh you're right. I haven't noticed that actually. And it's been months since that change has been made. There is a UX lesson there :)

Comment: @ssg: This is a great feature if implemented especially now that mobile devices also have feed. Edit the question to bump it to the front, let's see if this can get more votes.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately I believe that it is not possible. The *Hot Questions* shows questions from all sites, disregarding whether you have an account there or not. For example, now it shows some questions from *ux.stackexchange.com* for me, and I don't even know what that site is about. So deleting the account will not help (*off-topic: is it even possible to delete an account? :S*).

I was unable to find any way to filter those questions too. All I can think about is adding specific tags into your *ignored tags* on a specific site. I don't think it will remove any questions from the *hot questions* though, but it may help you at least not to come across such questions when serfing the site itself.

It would be nice to have an option to filter the sites, though, so maybe you should edit your question, and add a *feature-request* tag.